# How do I create a JSON format for Map[Int, Int] using Play Framework JSON libs?

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'd like to serialize a `Map[Int, Int]` using the Play Framework JSON libraries.  I want something like

`import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val formatIntMap = Json.format[Map[Int, Int]]`

That code however gets an `No unapply function found` which I think is referring to the fact that there is no extractor for `Map` since it isn't a simple case class.

Comment: I will get you part-way there by pointing to the existing Reads code for `Map[String, _]` in play.api.libs.json.Reads, Reads.scala.  That should be a good starting point.

Comment: How do you want this encoded? As an object with the keys converted to strings, as an array of two-element arrays, etc.?

Comment: Ah, I was thinking just a JS object with integer keys or, if that's not legal, then string keys.

Answer (score 1):

It will try to make a JsObject but is failing as it maps a String to a JsValue, rather than an Int to a JsValue. You need to tell it how to convert your keys into Strings.

```
  implicit val jsonWrites = new Writes[Map[Int, Int]] {
    def writes(o: Map[Int, Int]): JsValue = {
      val keyAsString = o.map { kv => kv._1.toString -> kv._2} // Convert to Map[String,Int] which it can convert
      Json.toJson(keyAsString)
    }
  }
```

This will turn a Map[Int, Int] containing  0 -> 123 into

```
JsObject(
    Seq(
        ("0", JsNumber(123))
    )
)
```

Comment: could you add the corresponding jsonReads?