# Scala Play Json Format for Map[Locale, String]

Tags: json, scala, playframework, play-json

I have objects of type

```
Map[java.util.Locale, String]
```

How can I make Json Writes / Reads for this? I have looked at a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285760/play-json-formatter-for-mapint) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224694/how-do-i-create-a-json-format-for-mapint-int-using-play-framework-json-libs) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33781605/scala-play-2-4-json-format-issue), but couldn't come up with a solution myself. I got (but not tested yet) something for Locale

```
implicit val localeReads: Reads[Locale] = new Reads[Locale] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Locale] =
    json match {
      case JsString(langString) => JsSuccess(new Locale(langString))
      case _ => JsError("Locale Language String Expected")
    }
}

implicit val localeWrites: Writes[Locale] = new Writes[Locale] {
  def writes(locale: Locale) = JsString(locale.toString)
}
```

How can I then use this in

```
implicit val myMapReads: Reads[Map[Locale, String]] = ???
implicit val myMapWrites: Writes[Map[Locale, String]] = ???
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
implicit val localeReads: Reads[Locale] = new Reads[Locale] {
  def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Locale] =
    json match {
      case JsString(langString) => JsSuccess(new Locale(langString))
      case _ => JsError("Locale Language String Expected")
    }
}

implicit val localeWrites: Writes[Locale] = new Writes[Locale] {
  def writes(locale: Locale) = JsString(locale.toString)
}

implicit val myMapWrites: Writes[Map[Locale, String]] = new Writes[Map[Locale, String]] {
  override def writes(o: Map[Locale, String]): JsValue = Json.toJson(o)
}

implicit val myMapRead: Reads[Map[Locale, String]] = new Reads[Map[Locale, String]] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Map[Locale, String]] = JsSuccess {
    json.as[JsObject].value.map {
      case (k, v) => (new Locale(k), v.as[String])
    }.toMap
  }
}
```

Basically play already knows how to convert a `Locale` to json because of the `Writes` you provided so simply calling `toJson` will work.

For the `Reads` it's a bit more complex and you have to do a mapping, `.value` returns a `Map[String, JsValue]` where the first represents the `Locale` object and the second a simple string so calling `as[String]` will already give you what you want.

Note that I've wrapped everything in a `JsSuccess` but you may assume that the json you got cannot be converted to `JsObject`, apply a try/catch, and decide wether you want to return success or failure.

Comment: Thanks - you put me on the right track! For some reason, the `override def writes(o: Map[Locale, String]): JsValue = Json.toJson(o)` in `myMapWrites` was entering an endless recursive loop that eventually would fire a `StackOverflowException` (!!), but it was easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that will create a `Format[K,V]` for you if `K` serialises to a `JsString`:

```
/** Play Json only supports Map[String,V]. This function creates a format for Map[K,V]. The type K should produce a JsString.
 * Otherwise the serialisation will fail. Which should be good enough since in valid json keys can only be strings. 
*/
def mapFormat[K, V](implicit fk: Format[K], fv: Format[V]): Format[Map[K, V]] = 
  new OFormat[Map[K, V]] {
    override def writes(o: Map[K, V]): JsObject = {
      val stringMap = o.map { case (k, v) => (Json.toJson[K](k).as[JsString].value, v) }
      Json.toJson(stringMap).as[JsObject]
    }

    override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Map[K, V]] = {
      for {
        stringMap <- Json.fromJson[Map[String, V]](json)
        _         <- Json.fromJson[Set[K]](Json.toJson(stringMap.keySet))
      } yield stringMap.map { case (k, v) => (Json.fromJson[K](JsString(k)).get, v) }
    }
  }
```